# How to create and iterate over a List of graphids (Apache AGE)?

Tags: c, postgresql, apache-age

I'm creating a function for Apache AGE, and I need to iterate over a `List` of `graphids`, how should I do it properly?

- The `List` I'm referring to is the PostgreSQL defined struct in this file -> [Postgres' GitHub repository Link](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/6f1cf2efbd0199c58db9f256ade48f42f56cab49/src/include/nodes/pg_list.h#L45)
- `graphid` is just an `int64`.

What I'm essentially trying to do is this:

```
graphid new_graphid = 0;
graphid vertex_to_connect = 0;
List* graphids_array = NIL;

(...)

for (int64 i=(int64)1;i<graph.graph_size;i++)
{  
        new_graphid = create_vertex(&graph);

        graphids_array = lappend_int(graphids_array, new_graphid);
        
        for(int64 j = 0; j<graphids_array->length-1; j++)
        {
            vertex_to_connect = list_nth_int(graphids_array, j);
            connect_vertexes_by_graphid(&graph,
                                        new_graphid,
                                        vertex_to_connect);
        }
}

(...)
```

The problem happening is that the `vertex_to_connect` variable is not receiving the proper `graphid` (which should be a big number like 844424930131970), instead, it's getting small values that seems to be from the `j` variable.

Any help on showing where I could be mistaken is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to iterate through a `List` you can use the `foreach` loop with a `ListCell` iterator. Here is an example of how you can do this:

```c
List *graphid_list = NIL;
ListCell *lc;

// Go through all cells in the list.
foreach (lc, graphid_list)
{
    // Code goes here.
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `ListGraphId` structure to create your list. Since it's only `graphid`s, I believe it will do the trick. Then, you would need to create an iterator to peek at each element of the list as a `GraphIdNode`. I believe it would be necessary to create a `for` or `while` loop for this, but then update at the end of the loop for the iterator to be the next value of the `GraphIdNode`. So, something like this would traverse the entire list:

```c
    ListGraphId *container;
    GraphIdNode *current = get_list_head(container);
    GraphIdNode *previous = NULL;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = next_GraphIdNode(current);
    }
```

You can find more about it at `src/backend/utils/adt/age_graphid_ds.c` and `src/include/utils/age_grapid_ds.h`.

https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/age_graphid_ds.c

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated code which can be helpful in your case:

```
 graphid new_graphid = 0;
graphid vertex_to_connect = 0;
List* graphids_array = NIL;

// ...

for (int64 i = 1; i < graph.graph_size; i++)
{
    new_graphid = create_vertex(&graph);

    graphids_array = lappend(graphids_array, graphid_to_const_ptr(new_graphid));

    for (int64 j = 0; j < list_length(graphids_array) - 1; j++)
    {
        vertex_to_connect = *(graphid*)list_nth(graphids_array, j);
        connect_vertexes_by_graphid(&graph, new_graphid, vertex_to_connect);
    }
}
```

In this updated version, we used lappend() inn place of lappend_int() for appending. For converting to pointer value you can use **graphid_to_const_ptr()**

Additionally, we replaced **list_nth_int**() with **list_nth()** for the retrieval.

Hope it would help you!